# Explicit description for dual to cohomology class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

Here's an inductive definition of a particular Bott tower manifold from https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/on-a-construction-in-bordism-theory/52DF8C16B5576A077781A1BB77CD5D77 . Let $B_{1}:=\mathbb{C} P^{1}$. Let $B_{n}$ be the (fiberwise) projectivisation of the vector bundle $\gamma_{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{C}\to B_{n-1}$, where $\gamma_{n-1}$ is the universal linear bundle over $B_{n-1}=\mathbb{P}(\gamma_{n-2}\oplus\mathbb{C})$. Consider the manifold $B_{q}\times B_{p}$ for $p,q>0$. Let $b_{1,p}, b_{2,q}$ be the cohomology classes $c_{1}(\gamma_{p}),c_{1}(\gamma_{q})$, resp. (I omit the pullbacks to $B_{q}\times B_{p}$.)

Now I want to know an explicit description of the Poincare-dual complex submanifold $B(p,q)$ for the cohomology class $b_{1,p}+b_{2,q}$ in $B_{q}\times B_{p}$.

It is easy to check that $B(1,1)\cong\mathbb{C}P^{1}$.

Also the construction above looks similar to the construction of the Milnor hypersurfaces $H_{i,j}\subset\mathbb{C}P^{i}\times\mathbb{C}P^{j}$. The latter are given by the explicit (1,1)-degree equation 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\min{i,j}}x_{k}y_{k}=0
$$

in the corresponding homogeneous coordinates and admit the structure of the projective fiber bundle. (Check 6.2 of http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Complex_bordism#Milnor_hypersurfaces .)